# how to use .jar files in netbeans8

Tags: java

It is the first time for me to work on a project with external library.

I have downloaded svnkit-1.8.10 which consist of three files:

```
-svnkit-1.8.10-sources

-svnkit-cli-1.8.10-sources

-svnkit-javahl16-1.8.10-sources
```

First one is enough to complete my job. I tried to add it by 
right clicking on Libraryes -> then add JAR/Folder

[image]

It successfully added the library. However in the code I could not make it work.
It gave me package does not exist.

[image]

Comment: Do the JAR files contain .class files or .java files? You'll need .class files, but the "-sources" appendix hints that you have the .java source files...

Comment: you are adding jar containing the sources. Instead add the jar containing binaries.

Comment: What you have downloaded is http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/tmatesoft/svnkit/svnkit/1.8.10/svnkit-1.8.10-sources.jar.

What you need to download is http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/tmatesoft/svnkit/svnkit/1.8.10/svnkit-1.8.10.jar.

Download the jar file from 2nd link and add it to libraries.
You are good to go.


Also, remove the old jar file first and then add the new jar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for JAR files which contain .class files instead of .java (source) files.

Once you have the basics, I recommend to use a tool which supports Maven Dependencies, eg. Maven itself: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/public-book.html

These tools can download and manage dependencies from private or public Maven Repositories such as Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/

You can also manually download artifacts from there, eg. the [svnkit](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.tmatesoft.svnkit%22).

Comment: I checked but, neither of them contain .class files.

Comment: @donanimsal That's what I said. You need another JAR which contains the .class files. Check the svnkit link I provided in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I answered the question in the comments section.
Just posting it as an answer so that it will be helpful for others who visit this page.

The jar file which is currently added in the libraries is [svnkit-sources](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/tmatesoft/svnkit/svnkit/1.8.10/svnkit-1.8.10-sources.jar) which contains `.java` files only.

To use external libraries in your project, you need to add the jar file containing `.class` files which is available [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/tmatesoft/svnkit/svnkit/1.8.10/svnkit-1.8.10.jar).